# Can not extend this JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, function, prototype, strict

I checked some question with similar issues but could not cope with mine where I have a **file.js**:

```
'use strict'

function singlyLinkedList() {
  if (this ) {
    this.head = null
  }
}

singlyLinkedList.prototype.append = function(value) {
  let node = {
    data: value,
    next: null
  }
  if( !this.head ) {
    this.head = node
  } else {
    let pointer = this.head
    while( pointer ) {
      pointer = pointer.next
    }
    pointer.next = node
  }
}
```

Which I call from **index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Test </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="file.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      let linkedList = singlyLinkedList()
      let integersArray = [1, 22, 333, 4444]
      integersArray.forEach(element => linkedList.append(element))

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Navigating this HTML file using Chrome browser and checking the console, shows this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of undefined

How to fix this?

**Update:**

The second issue I have with this (maybe a separate question?) is that if I write:

```
function singlyLinkedList() {
    this.head = null
}
```

I get this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'head' of undefined

Comment: `singlyLinkedList` isn't returning anything. If you wanted an instance, use `new`.

Comment: or, you can return `this` from `singlyLinkedList`

Comment: @Tzelon I tried your idea but after removing the `if` statement and did: `this.head = null` then `return this.head` but I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'head' of undefined`

Comment: I think you need to use it like ``let linkedList = new singlyLinkedList()``

Comment: @CertainPerformance is right. you need to use `new' to get an instance. sorry

Comment: @CertainPerformance I tried that solution before asking: I instantiated my function and then I applied `prototype` on the instance, but I am still getting the same error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'append' of undefined`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. No errors are thrown when you just use `new`.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ regarding second issue, why don't you set `head = null` in the <script> itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

few things you need to take care of,

1. Use `new` keyword to create an instance of 'singlyLinkedList'
2. your terminating condition of `while` loop is not correct. it should be `while( pointer.next )`

check below version,

```js
//create a `file.js` file and put this code inside that. running this code snippet on stackoverflow util wont work as you need a separate `file.js`

'use strict';

function singlyLinkedList() {
    this.head = null;
}

singlyLinkedList.prototype.append = function(value) {
    let node = {
        data: value,
        next: null
    };
    if( !this.head ) {
        this.head = node
    } else {
        let pointer = this.head;
        while( pointer.next ) {  //check this
            pointer = pointer.next
        }
        pointer.next = node
    }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Test </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="file.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
        let linkedList = new singlyLinkedList(); // check this
        let integersArray = [1, 22, 333, 4444];
        integersArray.forEach(element => linkedList.append(element));
        console.log('linkedList: ', linkedList);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

it will log something like,

[image]

And I strongly believe you need to use a `new` keyword for creating an instance of `singlyLinkedList` function as you want to use the benefit of the `prototype` concept

Comment: Thank you but that is how I used `new` in the very beginning (sorry for not mentioning that)

Comment: then what was the issue?

Comment: It was the first one I shared: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of undefined`. Did you run your solution the way I did, meaning saving JS code in a separate file and then calling it from an HTML file?

Comment: yes, its working perfectly fine and logging the desired output in console, let me update the answer

Comment: Strange ... I am using both Firefox and Chrome ... did you also use 'strict mode' as in my code?

Comment: You have provided enough effort and evidence, thank you, but I really wonder if there is a ghost in my browser ...

Comment: it works on a virtual machine and an other desktop computer running Windows ... I am going to accept your answer because the error occurs only on my laptop's browser. Thank you